# Crystal Reports & VBScript - Could Not Locate Automation Class

Tags: scripting, vbscript, crystal-reports, automation, crystal-reports-2008

First off, I have very little Crystal Reports experience, so apologies in advance if this is a stupid question. I had this "fantastic" work project dumped on me when a co-worker left, so I'm hoping someone can help as most of the Business Objects links I find that might have solutions just redirect to a generic SAP splash page.

So I have a few hundred Crystal Reports (mostly File Schema 10.2, although some are 8.5 or 12.0) that are stored on a server.  All of them have an associated VBScript file that calls them in the following way:

```
Set AppCrystal = WScript.CreateObject("CrystalRuntime.Application.10")


Set CrystalReport = AppCrystal.OpenReport("<file path to report>")
Set CrystalOptions = CrystalReport.exportOptions
CrystalOptions.DestinationType = 1
CrystalOptions.FormatType = 36
CrystalOptions.DiskFileName = "<file path to output excel file>"
CrystalReport.Export False
```

According to BO, this should be correct.  See the following links about the CR API:

http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/RDC_SDK/rdc_com_dg_doc/doc/rdcsdk_com_doc/RDC_ObjectModel62.html

http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/RDC_SDK/rdc_com_dg_doc/doc/rdcsdk_com_doc/RDC_ObjectModel151.html#1387900

http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/RDC_SDK/rdc_com_dg_doc/doc/rdcsdk_com_doc/RDC_ObjectModel8.html#1646326

So basically the script just executes the report and outputs it to an Excel file.  This works great on the old server, but when I try to execute this script on the new server I get the following error:

[image: CRerror]

I assume this is because there's some kind of runtime components I need to install, but I can't for the life of me figure out what.  I found this page: https://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56787567

But none of the files I've tried to download have worked, and, frankly, I've found SAPs documentation to be sub-par in this area.  I do have Crystal Reports 2008 available, so if I need to update the vbscript to use **CrystalRuntime.Application.12** or something and then install the newest runtime files for Crystal Reports 2008 on the server, that'd be fine. But I still need to know what runtime files to use? Nothing I can find has worked. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this type of call to a Crystal report uses the RDC Report Engine, unfortunately CR 10 is no longer available. You can still get CR XI R2 which still deployed the RDC and it's version 11.5.

There is no RDC in CR 2008, it was actually deprecated in CR 9 and now no longer shipped.

Only other option you have is to convert your app to use Visual Studio .NET and use one of the current CR 2008 or CR for VS 2010 components and rewrite your app to .NET Framework.

No more VB Scripting supported, but that was just the Dev Language...

I ended up just upgrading to CR 2008, and using .NET console projects to replace the VB scripts.

Comment: Glad to see you answered your own question! Sorry nobody could help you earlier.

Comment: No worries, I figured it was a long shot anywho...Crystal Reports FTL. ;)