# Using PHP and COM objects to access Crystal Reports XI (Version 14.0.4.738 RTM)

Tags: php, com, crystal-reports

I have the following PHP code snippet written in an attempt to use COM to access Crystal Reports XI (Version 14.0.4.738 RTM):

```
$ObjectFactory = new COM("CrystalReports14.ObjectFactory.1") or die("CR loading failed");
$crapp = $ObjectFactory->CreateObject("CrystalReports14.ObjectFactory.1"); 
$creport = $crapp->OpenReport($rptFile, 1);
...
```

The first two lines seems to be ok on the surface.  The third line throws an error, however:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method variant::OpenReport() in ...
```

I am not 100% certain that I have done the CreateObject() call (second line) correctly; it seems oddly redundant that I am using the same string for the first line and second line.  But maybe that's the way it is.

After searching on the web for quite literally 2 or 3 hours, I am starting to think that there is no documentation on this, but refuse to think that nobody has ever done this before!  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that you use ObjectFactory in the ProgID to create the COM.
Object factories, in COM, have a specific meaning and usually they are not applications.

I have found a question related to Crystal Reports and there they use a string that seems to me much likely to be the application ID. You should try it:
[Crystal Reports & VBScript - Could Not Locate Automation Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589982/crystal-reports-vbscript-could-not-locate-automation-class)

Comment: Thank you very much @carlos-e-ferro.  Do you know how I can find appropriate application ID?  Following the link you provided, I'm currently trying this:

$ObjectFactory = new COM("CrystalReports14.ObjectFactory.1") or die("CR loading failed");
$crapp = $ObjectFactory-> CreateObject("**CrystalDesignRunTime.Application.14**"); 
$creport = $crapp->OpenReport($my_report, 1); 

And I'm getting this error on the second line: 'com_exception' with message 'Source: Unknown Description: Unknown'

Re. the boldfaced part of the code, I have tried .14, .11., and removing it; all failed with same msg.

Comment: I don't know the PHP syntax, but I think that 
$crapp = new COM("CrystalRuntime.Application") or die("CR loading failed");
$creport = $crapp->OpenReport($rptFile, 1);
is the way I would try first.
As you said, there should not be necessary to do COM and CreateObject with the same ID.

Comment: this is the error I get when I try your recommendation: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message `Failed to create COM object 'CrystalRuntime.Application': Invalid syntax ' in C:\inetpub\wwwtest\testing.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwtest\testing.php(11): com->com('CrystalRuntime....') #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwtest\testing.php on line 11`.  Seems that no such application ID "CrystalRuntime.Application" exists.  Thank you.

Comment: You should check in your registry, using Regedit, under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and see what application you have for CrystalResports, registered there.
It may be CrystalReports14.Application, or CrystalDesignRunTime.Application. The last number after the dot is just version number, if you omit it, it uses the most recent

Comment: Sorry for this newbie question -- What am I looking for under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT?  I see 2 entries starting with CrystalBWQueryReportWrapper.*, 1 under CrystalClientDoc.*, 2 under  CrystalConnector.*, a lot under CrystalEnterprise.*, a lot under CrystalEnterprise14.*, a lot under CrystalReports.*, a lot under CrystalReports14.*, and 1 under CrystalReportsLauncher.*.  I don't see the word "Application" in the key name for any of them.

Comment: Never mind, I am almost as new into this as you... and don't have PHP nor CrystalReports. I do a lot of Excel automation, and in my registry I have Excel.Application key, with subkeys CLSID and CurVer, and also the version Excel.Application.12. I would expect to see something similar with CrystalReports and 14.
CrystalClientDoc is, most likely, the expected class of the result of OpenReport. I don't think that Connector could be the main point for anything, either. But I don't know which would be the string to identify the "main " application

Comment: Thanks so much for trying Carlos.  I looked through as many registry entries as I have patience for (I gotta say, most of them!), but none look quite right.  They are all very specific such as **CrystalReports14.TextLine.1** so I didn't even try.  I will continue to poke around, and hoping someone else will come across this thread and offer different ideas.  Thanks again!